# How many years have passed between each season of Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

First I just wanted to know how much time has passed between "Winter Is Coming" (*Game of Thrones*, S01E01) and "The Dragon and the Wolf" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E07), but I guess a more specific answer would be of more value to the community.

Even after having read all of the books, I just have lost the overview how much time has passed. E.g. Sam is riding slowly from Oldtown to Winterfell during the winter. Even that must have taken a year or so... Anyone who can help me.

Comment: The wiki seems to state each season lasts a year and they are consecutive. However, that doesn't seem to fit with what we see.

Comment: It's roughly the same amount of time as the meta, non-fictional time that passes out-of-universe: ~1 year.

Comment: It's already been explained by the writers of the show that time passes differently between scenes for different characters, depending on what the plot demands. In other words, Sam leaving Oldtown and arriving 2 episodes later in Winterfell doesn't really say anything about how much time has passed by comparing it to other characters' paths. This is the reason why we see Varys cross continents within the same episode in Season 6. I'm not saying it's **good**, in fact I'd argue it's bad, but it's what it is.

Comment: Adding timeline to each event would be way too complicated for the writers, and harm the overall quality IMO. Free of this constraint, they can focus on other things, which is a good thing. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline) each season lasts a year with them being consecutive:

1. 298 AL
2. 299 AL
3. 300 AL
4. 301 AL
5. 302 AL
6. 303 AL
7. 304 AL

However, this doesn't appear to be too accurate and doesn't make much sense to the events we see in the show but it appears to be the only information we have.

Comment: That's a wiki**a**, not wiki - essentially that means it's most likely inaccurate or based on pure speculation. As a relevant example, the numbers you quote are not even explained or cited with a valid source to back the claims in the wikia article.

Comment: @GhotiandChips I know it isn't reliable as I state in my answer but as I also state it appears to be the only information we have so it's better than nothing.

Comment: What's "AL"? Years in the Westerosi calendar are noted "BC" and "AC" for "Before the Conquest" and "After the Conquest", respectively; "the Conquest" actually being Aegon I's 2nd coronation in OldTown, some ~2 years after the beginning of said conquest.

Comment: Besides 304 AC would mean Arya is 15 and I think they make an effort to make her look younger than that (Maisie Williams is 20 now after all), she is far too small to be 15 and looks more like 11-12 to me. The current book, dance with dragons, is set in 300 AC, the series handles those events in season 4 and 5 though.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I took the years directly from the wikia and they had AL, I thought it was odd too but I suppose that's another factor for the unreliability of the wikia.

Comment: So, you are saying __Sansa__ is now 7 year older :o

Comment: @Mat'sMug I've recently asked a question on SFF about this but it looks like the show deliberately uses AL instead. [Reference](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/174759/58193)

Comment: @Dulkan The show and books timelines are different with dates from Roberts Rebellion onwards having been changed for the show, especially to make characters older.

Comment: @GhotiandChips That's not a valid distinction. *Wikia* is the trademark name of a website for fandom *wikis*. A *wiki* is just a publicly editable encyclopedia. This answer does, in fact, link to a wiki. More specifically, it's a Wikia wiki. Wikipedia is another *wiki*, owned by a different company. Does that make sense?

Comment: @sgroves Actually, specifying that it's a wiki*a* is a very valid distinction, because it has the bad reputation of making claims with questionable or inexistent sources (pure conjecture is not rare on a lot of wikia pages). The reason it's even more germane in *this* case is because it's an instance wherein aforementioned reputation is, yet again, being shown to be accurate.

Comment: @GhotiandChips Each wiki on Wikia is maintained independently. Some are better than others, sure, but there's no reason to think that they're *all* inaccurate. I find info on Wikia to be generally correct, for example. And again, it's not "a Wikia". It's a wiki *on* Wikia. Wikia is a collection of wikis.

Comment: @sgroves That [your opinion] is great, but I never said they were all inaccurate. The buck stops whenever I'm being forced to defend myself against something I didn't say. ~

Answer (score -7):

It’s been 299 entire time, otherwise we would have seen them experience many Winters already, rather than the one that’s been coming since the beginning of the series, and only in the last season will we experience it, as “Winter is Here”. Finally.

Comment: You know that the seasons last for man years in Westeros?

Comment: I believe that it's been established that the world of GoT doesn't follow standard seasons.  there's even a quote that the current generation has experienced the longest summer in living knowledge.

Comment: He is right. Aren't they on earth?