# What is the current canonical age of Sansa, Bran and Arya Stark?

Tags: game-of-thrones

As we know, the ages of the characters on *Game of Thrones* can be very different from both the corresponding age in the books and the present age of the actors portraying them. Moreover, we don't really know exactly how much time has passed since the events of season 1. ([This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79791/how-many-years-have-passed-between-each-season-of-game-of-thrones) shows that the speculated time is one year per season, but that's not definitive.)

Now, ignoring Jon Snow's parentage for the moment, there are three trueborn Stark children currently in Winterfell: Sansa, Arya and Bran. My question is, what is their current age according to the show's canon as per the latest episode (S07E07). (An approximation or an educated guess will do if the explicit age is not known. I remember Sansa telling Tyrion her age back when she was at King's Landing, but I don't remember the episode.)

It would also be interesting to know how old Robb Stark was when he was declared King in the North.

Comment: I've edited out the second question which would make this too broad. And tbh the only real answer you have to this question is "we don't know"... timelines are vague in ASOIAF and even more so in the show.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ComicBookTime etc.

Comment: The analogy of comic-book time hardly applies. This isn't one character having constant separate adventures like Superman or James Bond or even Hercule Poirot. This is an intricate story with a beginning and an end. And I don't need to remind anyone that Winter is here--for all characters simultaneusly.

Comment: Sansa was 14 when she was married to Tyrion. I think her age gets brought up a couple of times during the back half of season 3.

Comment: With a simple google search https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-age-of-everyone-in-Game-of-Thrones-the-show-not-the-books

Comment: @TusharRaj Winter was supposed to arrive years ago, since the kids have visibly aged that much. Yet I don't think we've seen much hints of winter outside the North, and the army of the dead has advanced at such a slow pace that it is beyond unbelievable. To me "comic book time" is a broader concept, as in "don't try to tie it down to a particular time table with all its consequences, because then it stops making sense". Hence the lack of explicit time indicators, birthday celebrations, etc.

Comment: @BCdotWEB _"Yet I don't think we've seen much hints of winter outside the North"_ - Season 7 ends with it snowing just outside of King's Landing.

Comment: @BCdotWEB The slow march can be easily explained if, in fact, the Night King does have Greenseer type powers, which is believable from his ability to interfere with Bran's use thereof.  If he has some limited future sight then he might know "eventually there's gonna be a dragon", so he just patiently waits things out and lets events transpire as they need to to get his dragon.  That's why he didn't just snipe everyone on the lake like he did the dragon.  He was waiting, biding his time, allowing what he needed to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the beginning of the series, Sansa is 13, Arya is 11, and Bran is 10. Their ages are revealed in season 1 dialogue.

There are few clues for the exact passage of time across seasons. However, Daenerys states in S5E8 that Varys hunted her for 20 years:

> For 20 years the Spider oversaw the campaign to find and kill me.

The show begins 17 years after the rebellion (when Daenerys was exiled) and Varys flees King's Landing in Season 4. Thus, 3 years passed between seasons 1 and 4. This is 1 year per season, however we do not know for sure how much time passes from season 5 through the beginning of 8.

**If we do assume that 1 year passes for each season, it would make Sansa 20, Arya 18, and Bran 17 at the beginning of Season 8.**

As for Robb, he was conceived before Ned left for the war, making him ~17 at the start of the series.

Comment: 20 could easily be a rounded number.